# relationship between curvature and exterior differential operator

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading *selected topics in harmonic maps* written by James Eells and Luc Lemaire.

Let $\xi:V\to M$ be a vector bundle with connection $\triangledown$. In the book, author defines the curvature of connection $R$:
$$R(X,Y)\sigma=(\triangledown_X\triangledown_Y-\triangledown_Y\triangledown_X+\triangledown_{[X,Y]})\sigma$$
and exterior  differential operator $d:A^p(\xi)\to A^{p+1}(\xi)$:
$$d\sigma(X_1,\cdots,X_{p+1})=\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}(-1)^{i+1}\triangledown_{X_i}^V(\sigma(X_1,\cdots,\hat{X_i},\cdots,X_p))+\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}\sigma([X_i,X_j],X_1,\cdots,\hat{X_i},\cdots,\hat{X_j},\dots,X_{p+1})$$

Then I wonder how we can prove the equation blew
$$-d^2\sigma=R\wedge\sigma$$

Is there any reference? Any advice is helpful. Thank you.